# How to fix linuxbrew and gcc error while compiling R from source?

Tags: r, gcc, homebrew

After updating Fedora to 36 I am trying to compile R from source. [Here is what I did following these instructions](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/)

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/R-4.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf R-4.2.0.tar.gz
mkdir R42
cd R-4.2.0
./configure --prefix=/home/andrespara/R42 --enable-memory-profiling  --enable-R-shlib --with-blas   --with-lapack
make
```

I got this error

```
mkdir -p -- ../../../../library/tools/libs
make[6]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools/src'
make[5]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools/src'
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools'
make[4]: se entra en el directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools'
installing 'sysdata.rda'
/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/bin/exec/R: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/gcc/11.3.0_1/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib64/libicuuc.so.69)
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:151: sysdata] Error 1
make[4]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2
make[3]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library/tools'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:37: R] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src/library'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:28: R] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/andrespara/R-4.2.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile:61: R] Error 1
```

I tried this `brew reinstall srt`  but I didn't worlk.
This is the output of  `brew linkage gcc`

```
System libraries:
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
  /lib64/libc.so.6
  /lib64/libdl.so.2
  /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
  /lib64/libm.so.6
  /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  /lib64/librt.so.1
Homebrew libraries:
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgcc_s.so.1 (gcc)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libquadmath.so.0 (gcc)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libstdc++.so.6 (gcc)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/gmp/lib/libgmp.so.10 (gmp)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/isl/lib/libisl.so.23 (isl)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/libmpc/lib/libmpc.so.3 (libmpc)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.so.6 (mpfr)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.so.1 (zlib)
  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/zstd/lib/libzstd.so.1 (zstd)
```

I checked with brew and reinstalled gcc

```
brew doctor
brew list --versions gcc                                                                                                        
"gcc 11.3.0_1"
brew update
brew upgrade
```

How can I solve this?

**ETA:**
I took some drastic measures `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies gcc` and then starting again the whole procedure worked and I got *`R`*, but how can I solve this beyond just installing gcc back.

Comment: You are not actually using Fedora -- R builds fine there, and offers you 4.2.0 as an rpm too.  You seem to have an issue with your use of `brew` on top of Fedora.  I happen to use gcc 11 all day long and have no issues with building R release or the development branch.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yes, you are 100% right I have compiled R before with almost no issues, but how can I safely fix this brew installation?